# Why are there fewer female users on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, users

I've been here for a little while, but I've never seen a single female user. I know maybe there are some, but I've honestly never seen any.

I know that out there in the world the female to male programmers ratio is way better than here.

Is my appraisal of the situation correct and can anyone explain why representation seems skewed towards predominantly male participants on Stack Overflow specifically?

Comment: Did you conduct any kind of count? How do you know the actual sex of an account holder?

Comment: Because there are fewer female programmers in general? Not sure what you mean by a better ratio.

Comment: I've heard of several female programmers who choose to hide their gender while on online communities like Stack Overflow due to bad experiences. So even if there were a "gender" checkbox, we couldn't know for sure what the male:female ratio really is. Still, it's obvious of course that there aren't a *lot* of females around (look at the top 50 users...) but as to why, I can't think of an answer that wouldn't be wild speculation

Comment: @not Pekka: Nice try, missy.

Comment: We do have a female moderator - Anna Lear.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn The handbag fascination kind of gives it away. I still wonder whose profile image she's using though. Poor guy.

Comment: @BoltClock so someone finally saw through my fake beard? In a way, I'm relieved.

Comment: Actually @gparyani Anna and Lear are two cats. The female you see in their profile image is merely their caretaker.

Comment: 'What can Stack Overflow do to persuade female programmers to participate more?' ya same thoughts, but I earned more down votes

Comment: @Bart I think you misunderstood. I was talking *user names*, not real names. But it still proves my point: we do have at least one female moderator.

Comment: @MartijnPieters i guess you are a male? right?

Comment: @SobinAugustine I didn't downvote your question...I *flagged* it for closing. In other words, I like your idea, but it is primarily based on opinions and doesn't quite belong here.

Comment: @SobinAugustine: You can verify my gender by following the links from my profile, sure. But a quick search for `Rachel` on the users page gives me *8 pages* of users. `Emily` gives me another 7 pages. No way those are all frustrated male geeks looking for attention.

Comment: Never seen any? You don't have to look hard at all to see any

Comment: Well I do believe there were at least two females who voted to close this question.

Comment: A more useful question is why are there so many bad programmers. On SO and in general.

Comment: so.. guys go and discuss this topic in the ORIGINAL question

Comment: @gparyani I'm no longer a community moderator. I work for Stack Exchange now.

Comment: So we can conclude that at least 40% of SO's users is female now, right @bluefeet?

Comment: @AnnaLear I was referring to the diamond appended to your name.

Comment: @Bart 40 out of 100? no way..

Comment: @SobinAugustine What's there to discuss?  You've provided no proof to back up your claims.

Comment: @Bart It is very possible but 40% might be a bit high.  In my experience many females users choose to hide their gender for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: You never know...

Comment: Who cares about the male/female ratio? The real question is why aren't there more alcoholics on SO? If this was a _real_ programming community, there'd be a lot more of us around...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I'm just a little skeptical the OP has never run into any female users of Stack Overflow. 'Rose' yields 32 pages of users, 'Anna' 73 pages. Contrast: 'Martijn' gives only 6..

Comment: @Yannis: Who says there aren't?

Comment: @Anna so you were an "ordinary" moderator at some point? Always assumed you were always community manager and SE employee from the very beginning! :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Yeah, I was a [regular elected mod on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/election/2) for a couple months and [on Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/election/1) for almost a year before I got hired. :)

Comment: Maybe you've just been looking at the ones in relationships

Comment: Looks like your question got spanked by a chick.  And you want more estrogen here??  :oP

Answer (score 6):

Given that many names are pseudonyms and that there is no place to put gender on our profiles, it seems that you are assuming this.    Unless you knew who is behind the keyboard, this is just a generalisation.

Comment: A generalization, yes, but probably not an unreasonable one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, yes that is true.

Comment: [On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you're_a_dog)...

Comment: @Oded: Everybody knows [ChrisF](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/59303/chrisf) is a dog.

Comment: @Oded ...or a unicorn, or a Skeet clone, or a marauding alien...